# What tool for tracking application/db/service installations and dependencies?

Tags: dependencies

In our organisation, we have 4 layers of environments (DEV, INT, UAT, PROD). In each layer there are 1-3 sets of the following SOA environment (one per GUI application project):

- Around 5-10 physical/virtual servers
- 4 oracle databases
- 5 web services (4 have their own databases)
- 3 of the web services are consumed by other webservers
- A message bus being shared by everything
- 5-6 desktop GUI apps pointing at the web services
- One of the web services is a distributed grid computing thing with 1-64 nodes
- Other satellite apps (access, VBA) pointing at web services

So if you multiply all that out, you get quite a tangle of databases, web services and GUI apps pointing at each other.

Are there any tools (pref. web based) we can use to keep track of it all, better than a wiki? Specifically I want to know:

- What versions of X are installed where
- Which webservices/GUI apps are pointing at other webservices/databases/message buses
- Logical groupings that constitute an environment (e.g. XYZ INT)

Note we are 100% Windows-based. I am looking for a manual tool for recording/displaying this information.

Note I am not looking for:

- an automatic network-probing/discovery tool (unless it can read proprietary configuration files and DLL versions from locked down servers... that would be great!)
- automated deployment tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any enterprise-level CMDB should be able to do this. You define your CI with the proper level of granularity, and then define relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this would suit your needs exactly but it might be worth taking a look at GLPI:

http://www.glpi-project.org/spip.php?lang=en

Once you've added all your servers/desktops, you can add all the various software versions/databases and "install" them on the boxes. Clicking on the software will show you a list of machines that have it installed.

For apps pointing to databases etc I'm not sure how you would do it.

There's quite a lot to it, is highly customisable and there are various plugins available.